# Android: Manipulate image and add white border around the image

Tags: java, android, image

I want to manipulate my image by adding white space around images (border) in my application. The image will be shown with the borders in the view, the image should also be *saved/replaced* with the new border.

Comment: What you have try ? Do some google before ask

Comment: your question is adding frame to image?

Comment: give padding to your image view and set background of imageview to white

Comment: Of course I have done "some google" before asking. I just found ways to add white space as background on the imageView, but I also want to save/replace the image including the white space around it.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong keywords, you want to actually manipulate your image and add bordering. I included my answer with some help and links.

Comment: ok thanks. I have changed the title.

Comment: Great , now your question. Will help other people who are looking for the same answer. Don't forget to mark the correct answer as the *correct answer* ;)  Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an image manipulating library with the possibility of *bordering*.

For example [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) can do [bordering](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/); you can use the [ImageMagick Java bindings](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jmagick/).